# How to raise/escalate errors / missing features surfaced by PowerShell but caused by underlying Windows components?

Tags: windows, powershell

How are we supposed to raise/escalate errors or missing features that are surfaced by PowerShell but are actually caused by errors or missing features in underlying Windows components? For example [PowerShell/JEA#30](https://github.com/PowerShell/JEA/issues/30) is a bug where defining a JEA endpoint via DSC causes WinRM to hang. The bug appears to be in WinRM but how do I escalate it or route it to the right place?

Another example is the is no API for setting service recovery options, we can wrap SC.exe but that is it, is there away to propose / vote for API extensions with the Windows team?

Answer (score 0):

You do that via GitHub issues, see [Contributing to PowerShell](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/.github/CONTRIBUTING.md), if they determine that it is another Windows component, they will escalate it to that team